# Last cell in recurrent network always the most accurate

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, forecasting, rnn

I am using a recurrent network for time series forecasting.

The prediction from the last cell in the network always seems to be the most accurate. For example if I have 20 cells (so my input samples are of length 20), the prediction from the latter cells (e.g. cells 11-20) seem better than the predictions from the early cells (e.g. cells 1-10).

Is this normal?

Lets assume my network only has 3 cells. At present I would input data x(t=0, t+1, t+2) to obtain predictions for t=0, t+1, t+2.Is this the wrong approach? If I want good predictions at all timesteps, do I need to using a "moving window" i.e. should I use a rolling sequence of inputs:

```
For prediction at t=0, input x(t-2, t-1, t=0)
For prediction at t=1, input x(t-1, t=0, t=1)
For prediction at t=2, input x(t=0, t+1, t+2)
```

Comment: You should take care not to violate the nature of time-series predictions. How you describe your input/output data, it could be that in one single step, the network sees the data that it should be predicting. If you're unsure, [check out an answer I posted on this topic a while back](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/30908/45264).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using a recurrent network for time series forecasting.

Interesting would be especially the type of the network you chose. How many layers? How many neurons per layer?

> The prediction from the last cell in the network always seems to be the most accurate.

I assume by cells you refer to your **samples**. Always, if you learn in datastreams (online), the network in later iterations **has seen more data** than the network in early iterations. Thus, with having seen more samples, your predictions become more accurate. Of course, this assumes that you do online learning on your datastream.

> At present I would input data x(t=0, t+1, t+2) to obtain predictions for t=0, t+1, t+2.Is this the wrong approach?

This depends on how your RNN is set up. A [Jordan Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network#Elman_networks_and_Jordan_networks) for example has context neurons, which should do exactly what you propose. The reason for recurrency in the network is typically that you want to simulate short term memory - meaning, in a mathematical view, you want to feed information from previous iterations into the front of the network. Thus, since this feature should be taken care of in your RNN, I do not think it is good to extend your input, since you introduce additional, potentially useless weights **that have to be learned** by the network.